# What's the best way to move logic outside of a Vue project?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, structure, vite, business-logic

I have a few projects that all use similar services and stores.

I want to have a separate logic and connect all the projects to it.

Is it possible???

Comment: have you tried monorepos?

Comment: No, I don't try Monorepo.

Comment: Is there any project on a separate repository on the git.
Is it possible to use monorepos? @Abregre

Comment: I don't know the scale of your projects, but to use the same services from different projects, there is microservices architecture, but it only helps if you want to serve large scale applications(otherwise it is overkill). For smaller scale applications if you maintain all the projects in a monorepo then you could succeed communication between them internally.
Check https://monorepo.tools/

Comment: Perhaps you can extract the code into a library or package and then use this package into your other projects.

Comment: We have a few large scale projects that all use their own repository patterns. These repository are almost the same and I want to have a public repository that these projects can use. @Abregre

Comment: I haven't tried this.Do you explain more? @IVOGELOV

Comment: All these similar services and stores - combine them into an NPM package and then use it in all your projects.